# Split __HELLO____HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__ to __HELLO__ and __HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__

Tags: php, regex

I have some php code like this:

```
$input = "
__HELLO__
__HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
__HELLO____HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__";

preg_match_all('/__(\w+)__/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Currently the result of `$matches[0]` is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => __HELLO__
    [1] => __HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
    [2] => __HELLO____HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
)
```

As you can see my regex is interpreting `__HELLO____HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__` as one match, which I don't want.

I want the matches to return this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => __HELLO__
    [1] => __HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
    [2] => __HELLO__
    [3] => __HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
)
```

Where `__HELLO____HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__` is split into `__HELLO__` and `__HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__`. How can I do this?

<sub>(Each line will only ever have one underscore in between the outer underscores e.g. `__HAPPY__BIRTHDAY__` is illegal)</sub>

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Yes you're right @JayBlanchard I've written the php already but I thought it unnecessary to post. I'm updating my question right now.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code now @JayBlanchard

Comment: I would've just removed the PHP tag and left it as-is. @David

Comment: True, I could've done that @Daniel Maybe then I wouldn't have got any downvotes :) Anyways I needed the code version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `U` modifier. This makes quantifiers ["lazy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

```
$input = "
__HELLO__
__HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
__HELLO____HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__";

preg_match_all('/__(\w+)__/U', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => __HELLO__
    [1] => __HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
    [2] => __HELLO__
    [3] => __HAPPY_BIRTHDAY__
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Daniel . This is indeed the right solution and I'll accept it in a few minutes when it SO lets me.

Comment: ... and is more useful to know than the useless modifier U.